# KnockoutJS : apply binding after render causes "xxx is not defined"

Tags: javascript, web, knockout.js

I want to get rid of that error but i'm currently using KnockoutJS on a special block. The problem is that when ko read for the data-bind, my ViewModel isn't created yet. I bind it after ko is loaded.
Here is my HTML view :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} - Evosphere</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('design/img/icons/favicon.png') }}" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bitter' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <link href='{{ asset("design/css/resp_lg.css") }}' media="screen and (max-width: 1550px)"  rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='{{ asset("design/css/resp_md.css") }}' media="screen and (max-width: 1350px)"  rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    {% javascripts
    'js/libs/*.js'
    'js/Evo/BeforeInit/*/*.js'
    %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar-top">
    </nav>
    <div data-knockout="messenger-block">
    <div id="messenger-attachment-container" class="container-messenger">
        <div data-bind="foreach: conversations">
            Ohoh
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="messenger-dialog-container" class="container-messenger-bottom">
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="main">
    {% block body %}
    {% endblock %}
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

    {% javascripts
    'js/Evo/app.js'
    'js/Evo/*/*.js'
    %}
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}

    {{ include('AppBundle:Javascript:init.js.html.twig') }}

    {% javascripts
    'js/Evo/RequireInit/Utility/*.js'
    'js/Evo/RequireInit/Module/*/*.js'
    'js/Evo/RequireInit/Module/bootstrap.js'
    'js/Evo/RequireInit/Module/navigation.js'
    'js/Evo/RequireInit/Module/feed.js'
    %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
    {% endjavascripts %}

    {% block javascripts %}
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my JS :

```
function ConversationDialogViewModel(){
var self = this;

this.conversations = [1, 2, 3];
}
var $messegnerBlockKnockout = $('[data-knockout="messenger-block"]');
ko.cleanNode($messegnerBlockKnockout[0]);
ko.applyBindings(new ConversationDialogViewModel(),   $messegnerBlockKnockout[0]);
$messegnerBlockKnockout.show();
```

Comment: Where's the code that causes the problem? What is `xxx`? Please create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'm sorry i have no idea how to tell this in a better way. I'm just having a normal HTML page and, in the bottom of it, i include knockout and my ViewModel.

Comment: We need to see some **code**. Edit your question to include the relevant code and the exact error message or it will be impossible for anyone to help you. `xxx is not defined` can happen for a million reasons I can think of and I'm sure a million more than that.

Comment: Well i added more code then

Comment: @MikeC Strictly speaking it can only happen for a single reason, namely when xxx is not defined. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I find out that i was binding another VM to an unexisting DOM element. It looks like ko applied it to the whole document.